# Canonical URLs for REST resources

Tags: html, web-services, http, rest

With plain-old webpages, if you have duplicate content in two locations, you can flag one as 'canonical' so web crawlers and such know that this is just another reference to a resource and explicitly defines the URL of the 'true' location for the content.  This is done by using a link tag in the HTML `<head>` tags of the non-canonical page pointing to the original.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/the-real-url-of-this-content.php>
```

In the realm of RESTful web services:

1. Is this needed, recommended, or not advisable to do?
2. Is Canonical only a construct for HTML to flag content for search engines?
3. If needed, how is the same accomplished with HTTP headers?  I'm not return HTML (just a JSON object) so the link tag makes no sense...
4. Does it matter whether or not there is more than one URLs for a unique resource in REST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) potentially answers this.

1. Hard to say.
2. It's a generic link relation, but it has been "invented" by Google.
3. See the spec (you could use the HTTP "Link" header field as well).
4. No, it does not matter; but avoiding multiple URIs for the same thing of course is a good idea no matter what.

Comment: Answers just containing a link are not considered answers. Though in this case link rot is highly unlikely, adding a summary would still improve the usefulness of your answer and help in the findability of the question and answer through search engines.

Comment: RFC 6596 seems to only be concerned with HTML content.  The RFC provides the same method of specifying canonical inside the HTML Document head tags as I note in my question.  What about non-html resources without head tags like JSON, XML, etc...? That's the gist of the question.

Comment: Ray, the RFC is not specific to HTML.

Comment: Marjan, the "canonical" link relation has a spec, and I linked to it. What would be a good summary? "Here's the spec"?

Comment: @JulianReschke Thanks for adding to your answer--the reality seems is no one cares about it for services and there is no widely used method.  Regard #4, It's hard and sometime counter intuitive to avoid duplication in many ways. for example say an application has users and homes. You should be able pull details on either by unique ID /user/:id/ and  /home/:id/.  Users can also have one home and you should be able to find the home by the user without the home id like /user/:id/home/.  Now we have 2 URL's that are logical but return duplicate content.

Comment: They don't return duplicate content if /user/:id/home/ redirects or links to /home/:id/ instead.